# Why is getLine being evaluated when its value is not required?

Tags: haskell

If Haskell is lazy, why does `getLine` is evaluated in both of the following cases? Being lazy I would expect that in the case of `fa` the `getLine` would not be evaluated because its result is not being used subsequently:

```
let fa = do {
  x <- getLine;
  return "hello"
}

let fb = do {
  x <- getLine;
  return $ x
}
```

(I tested both cases in GHCi)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful now... ;-)

The result of `getLine` isn't a string, it's an "I/O command object", if you will. The code actually desugars to

```
getLine >>= (\ x -> return "hello")
```

The `>>=` operator constructs a new I/O command object out of an existing one and a function... OK, that's a bit much to wrap your mind around. The important thing is, the I/O action gets executed (because of the implementation of `>>=` for `IO`), but its result doesn't necessarily get evaluated (because of laziness).

So let's look at the implementation of the `IO` monad... erm, actually you know what? Let's *not*. (It's deep magic, hard-wired into the compiler, and as such it's implementation-specific.) But this phenomenon isn't unique to `IO` by any means. Let's look at the `Maybe` monad:

```
instance Monad Maybe where
  mx >>= f =
    case mx of
      Nothing -> Nothing
      Just  x -> f x

  return x = Just x
```

So if I do something like

```
do
  x <- foobar
  return "hello"
```

Will `x` get evaluated? Let's look. It desugars to:

```
foobar >>= (\ x -> return "hello")
```

then this becomes

```
case foobar of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  Just  x -> Just "hello"
```

As you can see, `foobar` is clearly going to be evaluated, because we need to know whether the result is `Nothing` or `Just`. But the actual `x` *won't* be evaluated, because nothing looks at it.

It's kind of the same way that `length` evaluates the list nodes, but not the list elements they point to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have two questions to make. First, when you desugar `foobar >>= (\ x -> return "hello")` it desugars to `... Just x -> return "hello"` isn't it? Second, I am not afraid of "deep magic", so, can you show to me such magic behind the implementation of `>>=` in the IO monad, so that we can close this Stackoverflow question in a complete and useful way for others to come? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's `Just x -> return "hello"`. And then, from the definition of `return` we get `Just x -> Just "hello"`.

Comment: My point is, this effect is nothing to do with the magical low-level implementation of I/O (which varies between GHC versions); it's common to *most* monads, including `Maybe`.

Comment: You said "the magical low-level implementation of I/O (which varies between GHC versions)". I hope the case if for an improved implementation across successive versions, keeping the same behavior ...

Comment: The *behavior* of the `IO` monad is specified in the Haskell Report, and does not change. The *implementation* is not specified at all, and can be whatever GHC (or any other compiler) wants it to be.

Comment: I will read the Haskell Report one day (lack of time now). Know I am going through Real World Haskell, and despite being an old book, there's still lots to learn. Thanks for your clear answer.

Answer (score 4):

Its result is being used, just not in the way you necessarily expect.  This de-sugars to

```
fa = getLine >>= (\x -> return "hello")
```

So the result of `getLine` is still passed to the function `\x -> return "hello"`.  Monads are inherently about sequencing actions together (among other things); that sequencing still occurs even if results are later not used.  If that weren't the case, then

```
main = do
    print "Hello"
    print "World"
```

wouldn't do anything as a program, since the results of both calls to `print` aren't being used.

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, but the point here is that `x` (and not `getLine`!) is the thing which lazy evaluation allows you to avoid evaluating. You can verify this by executing `do { x <- return (error "oh, I guess x was evaluated after all"); putStrLn "nah, x wasn't evaluated" }` in ghci. (You can know `x` isn't evaluated because you can see it isn't mentioned inside the lambda body; but you can't know `getLine` isn't evaluated unless you are privy to the implementation of `>>=`.)

Comment: @DanielWagner So, is there some internal definition for `>>=` in the IO monad that forces evaluation of the actions in both sides? I tried to find this implementation but couldn't. Where can I see it?

Comment: @mljrg [There is indeed.](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#bindIO) Beware: deep magic!

Comment: @DanielWagner Ok, I know it's using the State monad, but I suspect that the `ccall` construct is always executed, irrespective if its value is used or not in a subsequent action. Or .. or ... that `(World, a)` that every IO action returns and consumes is forcing all IO actions that involve side-effects to be executed irrespective if their values `a` are being subsequently used or not (Just guessing)

Comment: @mljrg It isn't using the standard `State` monad, but it is using something similar. You are correct that there's a piece in the runtime system that has to cooperate with the apparently (but appearances are deceptive) pure-Haskell implementation; this is commonly described by separating "execution" from "evaluation", as I think you are doing.

Comment: @DanielWagner Can you give a reference where the topic separating "execution" from "evaluation" is well explained in clear way?

Comment: @mljrg No, I don't. =(

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations, you've just discovered why Haskell is a pure functional language!

The result<sup>†</sup> of `getLine` is *not* a string. It's an IO action which happens to “produce” a string. That string is indeed not evaluated, but the action itself is (since it turns up in a `do` block bound to `main`), and this is all that matters as far as side-effects are concerned.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Really just the *value* of `getLine`. This is not a function, so it doesn't actually have a result.</sub>

Comment: This answer is incomplete; see that of @MathematicalOrchid.